# ssh -4 works but ssh -6 does not

Tags: ssh, ipv6

When I attempt to ssh into my server it hangs for a long time. Looking at the output from `ssh -vvv [host]` shows it hanging when it attempts to connect to my server using its IPv6 address, then timing out and connecting immediately using the IPv4 address. I've confirmed this by doing `ssh -4 [host]` and there's no delay in connecting.

What is wrong here? Is my server misconfigured, is my local computer misconfigured?

Comment: There's no way to know, from your description. You will need to check both of them.

Comment: Post your debug output

Comment: @MichaelHampton You must understand that I am asking this question as I don't know what to check.

Answer (score 1):

Can you ping6 your server?
If y, check your sshd_config, probably it's listening to IPv4 only? Did you specified any listen address in it?
netstat -tanp might help too.
If you can't even ping6 check your client's and server's v6 addresses and ip6tables configurations.

Comment: If it wasn't listening on IPv6 then the ICMP error message should stop the timeout and make the client continue. Either the IPv6 traffic is getting lost or there are too aggressive firewalls/ip6tables in place blocking the SSH and/or the ICMP messages.

Comment: Yes, maybe not listening AND miscondigured firewall.

Comment: When problems don't seem logical then there are often multiple causes at the same time :)